# Which C++ random number distribution to use for the Java skip list generator?

Tags: c++, random

The Java `ConcurrentSkipListMap` class contains a method `randomLevel` that outputs the following, according to *The Art of Multiprocessor Programming*:

> The `randomLevel()` method is designed based on empirical measurements to maintain the skiplist property.
> For example, in the `java.util.concurrent` package, for a maximal SkipList level of 31, `randomLevel()` returns 0 with probability 3/4, i with probability 2^(−(i+2)) for i ∈ [1, 30], and 31 with probability 2^−32.

This *looks* like a [geometric distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/geometric_distribution), but not quite. Is there some way to neatly define this in terms of the provided random distributions, or do I have to do my own manipulation, as such:

```
inline unsigned randomLevel() {
    auto randNum = distribution.operator()(engine); // distribution is std::uniform_int_distribution<>
    unsigned two__30{0x4000'0000};
    if (randNum == 0)
      return 31; // p(level == 31) = 2**-31
    else if (randNum >= two__30)
      return 0; // p(level = 0) = 0.75
    else
      return 30 - static_cast<unsigned>(log2(randNum)); // p(level = i) = 2**-(i+2)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This *looks* like a [geometric distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/geometric_distribution), but not quite.

You are right, but problem is only probability of `0`. Note that you can use `std::geometric_distribution`, by merging first two values into one.

```cpp
class RandomLevel
{
    std::geometric_distribution<unsigned> distribution;
    std::mt19937 gen{std::random_device{}()};
public:
    unsigned operator()() {
        auto result = distribution(gen);
        return result > 1u : result - 1u : 0u;
    }
}
```